# All subgroups of a finite abelian p-group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Given a finite abelian p-group: $G = \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n p^{k_i}\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ for some integers $k,k_1,...,k_n$.

Regarding elements of G as tuples $(x_1,...,x_n) \in G$, I can get subgroups by imposing one or more conditions of the forms:

(a) $x_i \equiv 0\pmod{p^m}$ for some integer $m$
or
(b) $x_i \equiv x_j\pmod{p^m}$ for some integer $m $

Are all subgroups of this form?

**Edit**: The answer is no as Alex Bartel commented. So let me extend condition (b) to:
(b) $x_i \equiv b*x_j\pmod{p^m}$ for some integers $m,b$
(or even, $\alpha_1x_1 + ... + \alpha_nx_n \equiv 0\pmod{p^m}$)
Also, let me extend the question: If the answer is no, can the conditions be extended a bit for the answer to be yes? More generally, is there an easy way to describe all those subgroups?

Comment: No. For example the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $(1,2)$ is not covered by any of your conditions.

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. Changed the question accordingly.

Comment: @Lee: $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n$ is a vector space over the field  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. You're looking for its subspaces. They can be described by equations "some coordinates are these linear combinations of the other coordinates". So you will need this type of conditions.

Comment: To expand on the comment by user8268: sometimes, you will need more than one congruence. E.g., the set of $(x,y,z)$ in ${\bf Z}_p^3$ such that $x\equiv y\equiv z\pmod p$ is a subgroup that cannot be described by a single congruence.

Comment: @Gerry: Yes. That's what I meant by "one or more conditions of the form". What about such groups which are not vector spaces?

Comment: I don't understand the $p^{k_i}$ in front of the $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$. That just has the effect of making the cylic group a cyclic group of order $p^{k-k_i}$ instead of order $p^k$. Wouldn't it be much simpler to simply write that $G$ is a product of cyclic $p$-groups?

Comment: @Arturo: You are correct, but the reason I wrote it this way is because I wanted all the coordinates to "live in the same world" so that writing those linear equations would make sense. How would you write it?

Comment: @Lee: Since you are writing congruences (not linear equations), if $a+p^{k_1}\mathbb{Z}\in \mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_1}}$ and $b+p^{k_2}\mathbb{Z}\in\mathbb{Z}_{p^{k_2}}$, with $k_1\leq k_2$, you can "compare" them either by performing congruences modulo $p^{k_1}$ of $a$ and $b$, or congruence modulo $p^{k_2}$ of $p^{k_2-k_1}a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Lee: I take it you want a *conjunction* of such congruences? Because you can certainly write your subgroup as a direct sum of cyclic groups, and then express the coordinates of a generator for each cyclic group using congruences; then every element would be expressible as a sum (disjunction) of such elements; but you want it to be an "intersection" of subgroups given by such conditions, right?

Comment: @Arturo: Yes. I mean - intersection of subgroups given by such conditions.

Comment: @Lee, good point, we're not actually in a vector space when we work modulo $p^m$ for $m\gt1$. We're in the next best thing, and much of linear algebra goes over. Does Arturo's answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewritten and** (I hope) **clarified**

Yes, every subgroup can be characterized as the set of tuples satisfying certain linear congruences in its entries. To be more precise, we have the following:

> Let $p$ be a prime. Then every subgroup of $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ (including the subgroups of a $G$ as given in the statement of the question) can be described as the set of elements $(h_1,\ldots,h_n)$ which satisfy a set of (at most) $n$ congruences of the following form:
>   $$\begin{align*}
> h_{\sigma(1)} &\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{j_1}}\\
> h_{\sigma(2)} &\equiv \alpha_{21}h_{\sigma(1)} \pmod{p^{j_2}}\\
> h_{\sigma(3)} &\equiv \alpha_{31}h_{\sigma(1)} + \alpha_{32}h_{\sigma(2)} \pmod{p^{j_3}}\\
> &\vdots\\
> h_{\sigma(n)} &\equiv \alpha_{n1}h_{\sigma(1)} + \alpha_{n2}h_{\sigma(2)} + \cdots + \alpha_{n(n-1)}h_{\sigma(n-1)} \pmod{p^{j_n}}
> \end{align*}$$
>   where $\sigma\in S_n$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, $0\leq j_1\leq\cdots\leq j_n\leq k$ are nonnegative integers, and $\alpha_{ij}$ are integers.

What follows is essentially the proof that submodules of free modules over PIDs are free, as described [in this previous answer,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3279/how-can-i-find-a-basis-for-the-kernel-of-a-homomorphism-on-a-free-abelian-group/32807#32807) particularized for this situation.

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$.

We proceed by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, and therefore is of the form $p^{j_1}\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ for some $j_1$, $0\leq j_1 \leq k$; thus, $(h_1)\in H$ if and only if $h_1\equiv 0\pmod{p^{j_1}}$, which gives the result we want.

Asume the result holds for subgroups of a product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, and let $H$ be a subgroup of $\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$.

If $H=\{e\}$, then we are done: $H$ is described by the congruences $h_i\equiv 0\pmod{p^{k}}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$. So we may assume $H$ is nontrivial.

Consider the projections onto the $n+1$ coordinates; if any projection, say the projection on the $j$th component is trivial, then $H$ is a subgroup of a product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, and can be described as in the proposition, together with the condition $h_j\equiv 0\pmod{p^k}$.

Assume then that all projections are nontrivial. Each projection gives a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, hence of the form $p^{r_i}\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, with $0\leq r_i\lt k$. Let $\sigma(1)$ be the index with the largest subgroup (i.e., smallest $r_i$, possibly $0$); set $j_1 = r_{\sigma(1)}$. Let $\mathbf{a}_1$ be an element of $H$ whose $\sigma(1)$ coordinate is $p^{j_1}$. The minimality of $j_1$ means that $\mathbf{a}_{1}$ can be written as
$$\mathbf{a}_1 = (a_1,\ldots,a_n) = p^{j_1}(b_1,\ldots,b_n) = a_{\sigma(1)}(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$$
with $b_{\sigma(1)}=1$, all $b_i$ integers.

Now let $K$ be the subgroup of $H$ corresponding to the kernel of the projection onto the $\sigma(1)$-coordinate; that is, all elements that have $\sigma(1)$ coordinate congruent to $0$ modulo $p^{k}$. By induction, there is a bijection $\sigma\colon \{2,\ldots,n+1\}\to\{1,\ldots,n+1\}-\{\sigma(1)\}$ and integers $\gamma_{rs}$, $2\leq r\leq n+1$, $1\leq s\lt r$ and nonnegative integers $j_2\leq\cdots\leq j_{n+1}\leq k$ such that the elements of $K$ can be described as
$$\begin{align*}
k_{\sigma(1)} &\equiv 0 \pmod{p^k}\\
k_{\sigma(2)} &\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{j_2}}\\
k_{\sigma(3)} &\equiv \gamma_{32}k_{\sigma(2)} \pmod{p^{j_3}}\\
&\vdots\\
k_{\sigma(n+1)} &\equiv \gamma_{(n+1)2}k_{\sigma(2)} + \cdots + \gamma_{(n+1)n}k_{\sigma(n)}\pmod{p^{j_{n+1}}}.
\end{align*}$$
Moreover, the minimality of $j_1$ ensures that $j_1\leq j_2$.

Now, $K\cap\langle \mathbf{a}_1\rangle = \{e\}$, and $K+\langle \mathbf{a}_1\rangle\subseteq H$. In fact, $H = K\oplus\langle\mathbf{a}_1\rangle$: given $\mathbf{h}\in H$, we know that the $\sigma(1)$-component of $\mathbf{h}$ is a multiple of $p^{j_1}$ (by choice of $\sigma(1)$), and so there exists $m$ such that $\mathbf{h}- m\mathbf{a}_1 \in K$. Hence, $h\in K\oplus\langle\mathbf{a}_1\rangle$.

Therefore, given $\mathbf{h}=(h_1,\ldots,h_{n+1})\in \displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$, we have that $\mathbf{h}\in H$ if and only if:

- (i) $h_{\sigma(1)}\equiv 0\pmod{p^{j_1}}$; and
- (ii) if $h_{\sigma(1)} = mp^{j_1}$, then $\mathbf{h}-m\mathbf{a}_1\in K$.

Thus, we only need to show that this can be expressed by congruences of the form described. Note that $h_{\sigma(1)} = ma_{\sigma(1)} = mp^{j_1}$.

Condition (i) on $\mathbf{h}$ can be written as
$$h_{\sigma(1)} \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{j_1}}.$$
By our prior description of $K$, condition (ii) can be described as:
$$\begin{align*}
h_{\sigma(2)} -ma_{\sigma(2)}&\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{j_2}}\\
h_{\sigma(3)} -ma_{\sigma(3)}&\equiv \gamma_{32}\bigl(h_{\sigma(2)}-ma_{\sigma(2)}\bigr) \pmod{p^{j_3}}\\
&\vdots\\
h_{\sigma(n+1)}-ma_{\sigma(n+1)} &\equiv \gamma_{(n+1)2}\bigl(h_{\sigma(2)}-ma_{\sigma(2)}\bigr) + \cdots + \gamma_{(n+1)n}\bigl(h_{\sigma(n)}-ma_{\sigma(n)}\bigr)\pmod{p^{j_{n+1}}}
\end{align*}$$
with the problem that $m$ depends on $h_{\sigma(1)}$.

However, $a_{\sigma(i)} = p^{j_1}b_{\sigma(i)} = a_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(i)}$, and since $ma_{\sigma(1)} \equiv h_{\sigma(1)} \pmod{p^{k}}$ then for each $i$, $2\leq i\leq n+1$ we have
$$ma_{\sigma(i)} = ma_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(i)} \equiv h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(i)}\pmod{p^{k}}.$$
Since $j_i\leq k$, we can then rewrite the congruences above as:
$$\begin{align*}
h_{\sigma(1)} &\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{j_1}}\\
h_{\sigma(2)} -h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(2)}&\equiv 0 \pmod{p^{j_2}}\\
h_{\sigma(3)} -h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(3)}
&\equiv \gamma_{32}\bigl(h_{\sigma(2)}-h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(2)}\bigr) \pmod{p^{j_3}}\\
&\vdots\\
h_{\sigma(n+1)}-h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(n+1)}
 &\equiv \gamma_{(n+1)2}\bigl(h_{\sigma(2)}-h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(2)}\bigr) \\
&\qquad\qquad\mathop{+} \cdots 
\mathop{+} \gamma_{(n+1)n}\bigl(h_{\sigma(n)}-h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(n)}\bigr)\pmod{p^{j_{n+1}}}
\end{align*}$$
which can be rewritten in the desired form by moving the $h_{\sigma(1)}b_{\sigma(k)}$ summand to the right hand side, and regrouping; this satisfies the conditions of the statement above, since $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ and $\gamma_{ij}$ are fixed, giving rise to fixed $\alpha_{ij}$ that do not depend on $\mathbf{h}$.

This establishes the induction step, and so the description.

Comment: @Arturo, isn't that subgroup of ${\bf Z}^3$ given by the congruences $b\equiv6a\pmod9$, $c\equiv15a+2b\pmod{81}$?

Comment: @Gerry: Hmmm... Yes. $2b = 9m+6a$, and plugging that for your $2b$ gives my $18m+27a$. So there may be a way, I'm just not seeing how to phrase it in general. Inductively, if I can figure out how to do it for the second coordinate, it should straightforward to go from there. I'll sleep on it. Thanks!

Comment: If it's any help, here's how I got there: general element is $(1,6,27)r+(0,9,18)s+(0,0,81)t=(a,b,c)$ with $a=r$, $b=6r+9s=6a+9s$, $c=27r+18s+81t=15r+2(6r+9s)+81t=15a+2b+81t$, and the congruences pop out.

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks. There's a few more simplifications that can be made (in the basis elements, you can always assume that any entry to the right of the "pivot" is a multiple of the pivot, for instance) which might make this doable in general.

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks again; that was very useful, actually. I think I got it, if my "you may assume"s are not invalit somewhere around the line.

Comment: @Arturo: Thank you for this very detailed answer. I will take the time to understand it.

Comment: @Lee: Hold off a bit. I'm planning to rewrite it for greater clarity, but I can't get to it until this afternoon. I will also take the chance to double-check all my "we may assume"s.

Comment: @Arturo: Feel free to rewrite the question itself too. Otherwise, I'll rewrite it after I read your answer to make it clear and use the same notation as you do.

Comment: @Lee: The question is fine; I think it's good to keep intelligible questions "as is", even if that means the answer needs to make extra-precisions. It helps readers see the process.

Comment: @Lee: I'm done rewriting. Let me know if this is understandable or needs more explanation.